# At runtime, unexpected and unwanted black border appears in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a problem with a multiple WinForms application. My environment is:

Windows 7 Professional SP 1
Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1 Installed Edition: Professional
Microsoft Visual C# 2008   91605-270-2967065-60743

In Visual Studio Designer, I have laid out the form as it appears to the left in the attached graphic. However when I execute the application and bring up the form, it appears as to the right in the attached graphic. The black area surrounding the form contents is unexpected and unwanted. All other forms in this application are displaying as expected.

[image: Black border appears in Winform at runtime]

I realize that it is probably a setting that I accidentally changed. I am currently seriously editing this form and may have changed something. I just can't find out what.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to set that Icon and Caption at design time. Setting it a run-time causes a call to `RedrawWindow`.

Comment: @Jimi Nope didn't do it. FYI I set the Size, Text, StartPosition, and Icon Form properties from the initialization in most of my forms. That's required because a form may depend upon what invoked the form. It's dynamic! All the other forms in this project (currently nine but expected to grow) work OK. Thanks for your thoughts but it is not the solution.s

Comment: You didn't mention anything about the docking/anchoring method of the Panel container. Since the Panel is offset by a `Caption.Height` value, it looks like the Panel is offset because the Caption is destroyed and redrawn. Check whether there's a difference in the docking/anchoring method. You didn't post any code, related to the controls' placement, so it's just guessing.

Comment: @Jimi Anchor (top, left) and Dock (none) are the same for all forms. Was a thought. I decided to take drastic action. I doubled the size of the form; moved all of the controls rightward out of the groupbox into the expanded form; replaced the groupbox with a panel of the same size; moved all of the controls back into the panel; and returned the form to its original size. Same problem. I wish to point out that the black area in the graphic I provided in the original question really appears transparent on a monitor. Thanks for your continuing help.